# Use AIML for Page Redirection

Tags: chatbot, aiml

I am developing an AIML chatbot using Program-O. Is there any way i redirect to a link mentioned in the user input. As in can i use the href attribute inside AIML? For example:

```
<category>
    <pattern>Go To google.com</pattern>
    <template>Can i put something here to redirect to google.com?</template>
</category>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using system element we can do that .
assuming that your using windows...

```
<category>
    <pattern>Go To google.com</pattern>
    <template><system>start "http://www.google.com"</system></template>
</category>
```